# DynamoDb.net: Adding In Operator , and get multiple values in Right way

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Dynamodb.net here
i am trying to get the two records using In Operator, when i am using the below code i am getting the expected output properly

**source_id is my sort key**

```
List<Object> users = new List<Object>(); 
            users .Add("Luke");
            users .Add("Ivan");
            object[] userArr= users .ToArray();
            var results = _dynamoService.DbContext.Scan<AITrackerData>(new ScanCondition("source_id", ScanOperator.In, userArr));
            foreach (var item in results)
            {

            }
```

Is this the right  way of getting data from dynamo dB? would it cause performance issue if i use `_dynamoService.DbContext.Scan`

I used the below  code but its not working, and giving error

> Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBException: 'Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation'

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
 var opConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig();
                opConfig.OverrideTableName = "User";
                opConfig.QueryFilter = new List<ScanCondition>();
                opConfig.QueryFilter.Add(new ScanCondition("source_id", ScanOperator.In, userArr));
                var response = _dynamoService.DbContext.Query<AITrackerData>(source, opConfig);
                foreach (var item in response)
                {
    
                }
```

Can any one please suggest the right way of getting data

Answer (score 0):

```
 object[]users  = { "Luke", "Ivan" };
            IEnumerable<AITrackerData> results =
                 _dynamoService.DbContext.Query<AITrackerData>(source, QueryOperator.Equal, users );


            foreach (var item in results)
            {

            }
```

can this be  used instead of In Operator, i tested this and i am getting the out put properly , can any one please suggest